# How to migrate from one cloudfront distribution to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We're using cloudfront to front end a web app (myapp.com with s3, lambda, athena, ... etc)
Before a new release we're creating an entire new distribution (next.myapp.com) with new code and content, testing and then would like to make it the live version of myapp.com.  But this doesn't seem possible.

Multiple Cloudfront distributions can't have the same CNAMEs so we can't change the DNS entry for myapp.com to point to the new service. 
Changing the distribution means there's a delay as the new config populates around the world.

Is there away of doing this using amazon infrastructure? Or am I doing this completely wrong?  Would like to be able to migrate the live service ASAP, but still have the existing version available for manual failback if the release breaks something

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible with only a very brief period of downtime, if you follow these steps.

Create the new distribution with the correct certificate but no Alternate Domain Name, and allow it to stabilize.

Change the DNS for the site to point to the new distribution.  This does not have the negative impact that you would assume, because the site continues to work on the existing distribution.  CloudFront does not differentiate between arrival endpoints -- it's only looking at the SNI and Host header, matching these against the Alternate Domain Name -- so the old distribution will continue to handle the traffic.

Edit the existing distribution to remove the Alternate Domain Name.  You do not need to wait for it to return to "Deployed" status.

Edit the new distribution to add the Alternate Domain Name.  You may have to attempt this more than once but it will eventually be accepted.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  Can you elaborate on what happens after the DNS is pointing to the new distribution but the alternate domain change hasn't been propagated.  If a webbrowser/client looks up the IP address of my site and makes the request to the new distribution will it be served correctly?

Comment: @NervousNigel CloudFront assigns a different endpoint hostname for each distribution, but the hostname for a given distribution, in DNS, does not map to anything unique to your distribition.  It typically resolves to IP addresses that are attached to pools of servers that can actually handle traffic for any distribution... and the correct distribution is determined by the HTTP `Host` header in the request... so technically it's pointed to the wrong hostname, but that wrong hostname ultimately still delivers traffic to a viable place and the request hits the old distribution.

Comment: Great answer - super helpful and worked perfectly for me. Is there a way to verify that assets are being served from the new distribution? I found the via and x-amz-cf-id headers but they don't seem to map to any id in the control panel.

Comment: @PaulOdeon the CloudFront log files would be the only simple way to affirmatively validate which distribution is handling a request. The value from the `x-amz-cf-id` response header appears in the CloudFront logs as `x-edge-request-id`.  The hex digits appearing in the `via` response header were undocumented at last check, but I have always suspected that they are correlated in some way to physical hardware handling a given request, so would tend not to prove anything by either changing or not changing.

Comment: ...of course, if you wanted to do something more sophisticated to identify the distribution handling a given request, a Lambda@Edge viewer response trigger could be written that would inject a custom response header to identify the distribution, since the [event data structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-response-viewer) exposes the distribution ID from the console to the trigger code as `event.Records[0].cf.config.distributionId`.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use `*.myapp.com` as CNAME for the new distribution, switch your DNS records to point to the new distribution and when the switch is effective you clean everything up.

See [Moving an Alternate Domain Name to a Different CloudFront Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move).

It's not possible to do this for a second-level domain (`myapp.com`) without contacting AWS. The solution is to use `www.myapp.com` for the live version and have another distribution only for the HTTPS redirection from `myapp.com` to `www.myapp.com` (or a redirection with S3 but HTTP only then). The CNAME for this distribution would never need to be updated.

Comment: But it appears you can't switch a second level domain name myapp.com without contacting amazon support, according to [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move-domain]

Comment: That's correct, to avoid this you should use `www.myapp.com` for the live version and `next.myapp.com` for the next version. On top of that, you should have a distribution that redirects `myapp.com` to `www.myapp.com` (with a distribution to have HTTPS redirect, with S3 you can do it also but HTTP only). Updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm, that's less than ideal, but I guess is the simplest way - I was hoping there would be some way to route the myapp.com,  Thanks for your help

Comment: This helped me to migrate domains that were not the apex, without downtime.